# EF Code First alter default Initial Catalog

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to change the default database entity framework, but the "Initial Catalog", is not being changed.

[web.config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pG5eg.png)

[Events - Visual studio 2015](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ty8jI.png)

How could set it?

Project is using:
- MVC 5 (Framework 4.6)
- EF 6
- SQL Server 2014 Express

Comment: Why don't you define a connection string?

Answer (score 0):

You will want an actual connection string. Depending on the code generation strategy you're using, the way to solve it is slightly different but all start from the edmx (which most likely will be there since its EF6).

If you are using model-first approach, right-click and choose "Generate Database from model". If you created the database first, choose "update model from database". Either way, you *should* get an update wizard where you must choose your database and at the bottom you will see the connection string it will create. Make sure "save connection string in config" is checked and click next and click finish.

You now have a connection string which will replace that defaultConnectionFactory you were referring to.

Lastly, if your edmx is in a different project, copy that connection string from that app.config file to your web.config file. If it's in the same project, there's nothing more to do!